# Populating a ViewPager with images from url

Tags: c#, xamarin

First of all, I followed the guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/viewpager/part-1-viewpager-and-views/) and implemented it. The guide uses static resources from which it gets the images. My application however, does an HTTP call and gets a JSON which contains links to images. I would like to pass the links to the ViewPager adapter so I can then populate it by using the Glide library. Is there any way to do that? I'm not linking my code since it's a complete copy of the one in the guide, using different names.

**HTTP Call**

```
public class JsonCallRequest
{
    public static async Task<JsonValue> CallJSON(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us some code w.r.t. http call. probably there is something we can help you.

Comment: @MukulVarshney I have added the code, after it is called, the JSON is conveted to a string. Eventually I manipulate the sting to a url pointing at the image. I want to pass the url to the adapter, after that I can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make your call to the server in the activity. Once you have your result back from the server I'd recommend you to read out the jsonDoc and see where the urls are hidding, in which parameters they can be found

Something like:

```
public class test : Activity{
    Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewPager;

    adapterTest adapter;

    public test(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {
    }

    public test() {
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        viewPager = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        adapter = new adapterTest(this);
        performCall();
    }

    async void performCall() {
        // Perform cal here
        var result = await makeMyCall();

        // Figure out the structure of the result
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        // Sample of selecting the urls from result using Linq
        IEnumerable<string> urls = result.Select(x => x.url);
        adapter.Urls = urls;
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

Next your custom PagerAdapter could look something like this:

```
public class adapterTest : Android.Support.V4.View.PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    public adapterTest(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {
    }

    public adapterTest() {
        this.context = context;
        Urls = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Urls { get; set; }

    public override int Count {
        get {
            return Urls.Count();
        }
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object @object) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        var imageView = new ImageView(context);
        // load image with glide
        imageView.SetImageResource(Urls.ElementAt(position));
        var viewPager = container.JavaCast<ViewPager>();
        viewPager.AddView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

You set the new property `Urls` in your adapter as soon as the information is received from the HTTP call & next you set the adapter of the viewpager, reloading all the views of your viewpager.